# Powershell - Sending Outlook email to multiple users using csv

Tags: powershell, csv, email, outlook

I'm trying to send a large number of emails using a CSV containing emails and serial numbers. I'm trying to send it through Outlook. csv contains the serial and then email. (JS9SDUS, some.dude@email.com). So far It's not working out too well.

```
 $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\poop\Desktop\TestSerial.CSV


foreach ($line in $csv){

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "$MainEID"
$Mail.Subject = "$Serial"
$Mail.Body ="Pay rise please"

$Mail.Send()
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see right off is the variable names you are using don't mean anything.  Try something like this:

```
foreach ($line in $csv){

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $line.MainEID
$Mail.Subject = $line.Serial
$Mail.Body ="Pay rise please"

$Mail.Send()
}
```